# Definition of Generalized Conic Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, definition, vector-bundles

Can some one help me understanding why the Definition of Generalized Conic Bundle is generalization of the Conic Bundle definition.

This is the definition of a conic bundle from "Comparison theorems for Conic Bundle"- P. E. Newstead 
[image]

And this is the definition of generalized Conic Bundle from "Cohomology of certain moduli space of vector bundles"- Vikraman Balaji
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first definition says that we have a bundle $Y$ cut out of the trivial $\mathbb{P}^n$-bundle on $X$ -- that is, $X \times \mathbb{P}^n$ -- such that the fiber over each point of $x$ is a conic and such that $Y$ is locally a quadric surface in some three-dimensional linear subspace of the $\mathbb{P}^n$ bundle.

The second definition replaces the trivial $\mathbb{P}^n$-bundle with an arbitrary $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle, and imposes the same conditions -- each fiber is a conic, and the family is locally cut out of $U \times \mathbb{P}^2$ by homogeneous quadratic polynomials.  This generalizes the first definition because we can take our $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle to be the one cut out of the trivial $\mathbb{P}^n$-bundle by the equations (1).

Comment: I am sorry, its not very clear to me what you are saying. There is no mention of $\mathbb{P}^2$ bundle in both of the definitions. Also, my problem is in  understanding the definition of generalized conic bundle from V. Balaji's paper.

Comment: In Balaji's paper, you start with a rank-3 vector bundle V and take $\mathbb{P}(V)$.  The projectivization of a three-dimensional vector space is $\mathbb{P}^2$, so $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle.